# Finding ip addresses associated with a domain name

Tags: google-ads-api

We are trying to exclude certain ip addresses (of competitors) from our Google Adwords campaigns.  Is there a way to find ip addresses associated with a domain like foobar.com?

Someone suggested we download a list of ip addresses from Arin.net, but I can't find anything like this on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Use java Inet class and retrieve the IP addresses of whichever domain you need.

Additionally you can use these links to do so

http://whois.net/domain-name-ip-address/

http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm